# What verb form is the phrase '見上げたんだ' using?

Tags: verbs, song-lyrics

From the song 'Nirvana' by Tia.
I am currently working on translating this song as an exercise and I noticed that this phrase is different from the verb forms I already know.

見上げたんだ

The meaning is supposed to be 'I looked up' - but wouldn't you just say '見上げた'?
What does this 'nda' mean? If it's casual speech for です in this case, why add だ to an already complete sentence?

Thanks very much!

Answer (score -1):

Simply put, it's used for emphasis.